# Joomla all versions not worked 404 pages on Litespeed server

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, joomla-3.4, joomla-3.3.x, joomla-4.x

i see front page without component, → 404 error not shows but i have its in my template..
error.php:
error->getCode(); ?> - title; ?>

i found very much articles, whats is maybe litespeed not support htacess rules, but they can read htaccess full rules, maybe.

tested all server configs, 404 page worked if no .htaccess in litespeed, buts site and virtuemart SEF links dead.
pludin 404 errors by virtuemart not worked too.
pls help !!!

when get php fatal error see page i think its component likely 404 page error.php
but understand why 404  error.php not worked

centos 7, litespeed, php 7.4.28
i see HTTP  200 OK anymore

Comment: server returns 200 OK not 404 status why ? joomla+litespeed

Comment: Please do not add question details as comments.  To make your question clear, you may [edit] your question as many times as you need.